# Add a Role to a SignalR client

Tags: signals, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I learning SignalR, and I would like to add a role to a signalr client.

In the official documentation, they said that it's possible to add a specific role to each client, and I would like to know who it's possible.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Manager")] – only authenticated users in the specified roles
```

So, can I do something like :
(in the server part)

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void addToGroupe()
    {
        //add a role to the caller client to authorize him calling function
        //Context.Caller ... ?
    }
}
```

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 2):

You decorate the method with that attribute, and use Form or windows authentication on the web server.

Comment: haa, I understand, it's the Windows Server roles ? when you create windows client. ok ok thanks !

Comment: Yes if you use the .NET client you need to set the credentials on the connection. Javascript client works out of the box